# How do I insert a value into a DB and preserve line feeds?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The value is (literal):

```
drivers.
CDL license.
Least.
```

It is stored in a variable that is called `ReturnedText`.

I want to update a record in DB and preserve the line feeds.

After it has been modified, it seems in the page that displays it as:

```
drivers.  CDL license.  Least
```

I tried to preserve the format by `HtmlAttributeEncode` and `HtmlEncode`:

```
Dim desc As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@formatDesc", SqlDbType.NText)
desc.Value = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(ReturnedText)

Dim Cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("
                                        update dbo.Positions 
                                        set description = @formatDesc where id = 123456"
                                       ,Conn)

Cmd.Parameters.Add(desc)

Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But when I display it in my page, it shows:

```
drivers.  CDL license.  Least
```

How can I save it with the format I see in text visualizer?

Comment: I have no issues inserting strings in to SQL with line breaks.  They always seem to come out just fine.  Can we see the code you are using to insert and read the data?  What data type is the field in the database?

Comment: You should stop using the ntext datatype. It has been deprecated because it is a pain to deal with. You should instead use nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key phrase is here (emphasis mine):

> But when I display it in my **page**, it shows:

This, plus the references to `HtmlEncode` and `HtmlAttributeEncode()`, indicate you want this in an HTML page. This is important: **HTML treats all non-entity whitespace the same**. A tab is a carriage return is a line feed is a space is two spaces. All a browser will do with that is put a space between words. If you view the source for your document in the browser, *you will see that the line breaks were preserved*, and merely not rendered by the html.

Therefore, to fix, this, you must use the `Replace()` function to replace the `\n` character with `<br/>`.  `HtmlAttributeEncode()` was a good attempt to fix this, but it [only handles a few specific characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The HtmlAttributeEncode method converts only quotation marks ("), ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<) to equivalent character entities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think HtmlAttributeEncode is going to take care of those line breaks for you. It will do quotes, ampersands, left brackets, etc.

Also, it's better to save the data as is, and only encode it when needed (when you output it in HTML). Some day that data could be needed for something else, used in a report, etc.  As you are outputting for web use you can convert the line breaks to html at that point.